# Finding all the constructors and member functions of class from llvm bitcode

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

In llvm we can find out all constructors or memeber functions of class using clang plugins like printfunctionames. Can we do the same, that is finding all the constructors and memeber functions of class from llvm pass ? I.e. in short can we find constructors and memeber fuctions from bitcode? 
Printfunctionnames is available in clang sourcecode . It takes cpp file as input and gives all function names. I am intersted in doing same from bitcode file. Is it possible ? If yes then please give some input on it so that I can proceed in that direction . Your help is so much appreciated in making me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what really want, but you just run `llvm-nm | c++-filt | grep Class::` to get what you describe.